# General formula of Fibonacci look alike series

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, fibonacci-numbers

I'm trying to discover the general formula of a series defined with recursion:

$$
a_1 = 2, a_2 = 3, a_3 = 4
$$
and
$$
a_n = a_{n-1} + a_{n-3}
$$

It looks like Fibonacci, but the starting points are different, and the rule is different.

I tried to compare to Fibonacci, but got nothing.

Anyone can think how can I reach the general formula (depending only on 'n')? Some material on how to reach Fibonacci's general formula might help (saw that a long time ago and can't find it, just found proof that the formula is valid, given we have the formula, which does not help me)

Regards

Comment: Any hints on how to discover $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$?

Comment: This is on [OEIS](http://oeis.org/A179070).

Comment: You need to find the roots of $x^3-x^2-1 = 0$. I don't think there is a nice formula.

Comment: Thanks @DanielR, but I mistyped, my $a_1$ = 2, not 1. But there should be an easy way to get to what I need

Comment: [Well...](http://oeis.org/A000930)

Comment: @DanielR, you're very awesome!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Letting $a_0=1$ extends the relation.

If $r_1,r_2,r_3$ are the three distinct roots of $x^3-x^2-1=0$ then the formula will be of the form:

$$a_n=\alpha_1r_1^n+\alpha_2 r_2^n +\alpha_3r_3^n$$

You can solve for $\alpha_i$ by looking at the equations:

$$1 = a_0 =\alpha_1 + \alpha_2 + \alpha_3\\2 = a_1=\alpha_1r_1+\alpha_2r_2+\alpha_3r_3\\3 = a_2=\alpha_1r_1^2+\alpha_2r_2^2+\alpha_3r_3^2$$

Unfortunately, the [cubic formula](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%20x%5E3-x%5E2-1%3D0) gives very messy values for $r_1,r_2,r_3$. The solution with the largest modulus is the real solution, $r_1\approx 1.4656$, so, for $n$ large, $a_n\approx \alpha_1r_1^n$. The other roots are $\approx -0.23279\pm0.79255 i$. These have modulus of about $0.826$ so they should pretty quickly contribute very little. For $n$ large enough, then, it will be the nearest integer to $\alpha_1r_1^n$. What "large enough" means depends on the values $\alpha_2,\alpha_3$.

Comment: Thank you. Can you give me some reference so I could deep dive? Something that would explain me how to get the equation that I should calculated the roots, and how to calculate the coefficients, and why does all that makes sense?

Comment: Look up '[linear recurrences.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Linear_homogeneous_recurrence_relations_with_constant_coefficients)' It is pretty obvious if $r$ is a root of a polynomial $p(x)=x^k-a_{k-1}x^{k-1}\dots-a_0$ then $r_n = r^n$ satisfies $r_{n+k}=a_{k-1}r_{n+k-1}+a_{k-2}r_{n+k-2}+\dots +a_0r_n$. Any linear combination of sequences satisfying such a recurrence also satisfies the recurrence. This gives all recurrences when $p$ doesn't have repeated roots, but is more complicated when $p$ has repeated roots.