# Closed form for recurrence relation

Tags: recurrence-relations, closed-form

Is there a closed-form solution to the following recurrence:

$$T(n) = T(n-1) + T(n-3)$$

If yes, what is it and how can it be proven/derived?

If not, then why because a somewhat similar recurrence like fibonacci has closed-form solution.

Comment: Fibonacci is solved by looking for solutions of the form $T_n=t^n$. Do the same here. If you find several solutions, any linear combination is also a solution.

Comment: There is a closed form solution. The roots of the characteristic equation are given by the Cardano formula, Unattractive but explicit.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/889311/general-formula-of-fibonacci-look-alike-series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The explicit formula looks like this:
$$T(n) = a_1 x_1^n+a_2 x_2^n+a_3x_3^n,$$
where $x_{1,2,3}$ are the three roots of $x^3-x-1=0$ and $a_{1,2,3}$ are determined by the initial conditions.

But through my magic crystal ball I see that you do not really want an explicit formula, rather you need a method to calculte $T(n)$ in short time for inputs up to $n\approx 2^{64}$. The following method takes only $O(\ln n)$ time:
The map $(T(n), T(n+1), T(n+2))^t\mapsto (T(n+1), T(n+2), T(n+3))^t$ is linear, i.e. given by some $3\times 3$ matrix $A$. Then we have $$(T(n), T(n+1), T(n+2))^t = A^n\cdot(T(0), T(1), T(2))^t$$
and we can find $A^n$ by repeated squaring in $O(\ln n)$ operations.

Comment: The characteristic roots are (according to maple)
\begin{align*}
  x_1 &= \frac{\bigl(108 + 12\sqrt{69}\bigr)^{2/3} + 12}{6\cdot \bigl(108 + 12\sqrt{69}\bigr)^{1/3}} \\
  x_2 &= \frac{\bigl(108 + 12\sqrt{69}\bigr)^{2/3}(-1 + \sqrt{3}i) - 12(1 + \sqrt3 i)}{12 \cdot \bigl(108 + 12\sqrt{69}\bigr)^{1/3} }\\
  x_3 = \overline{x_2} &= \frac{\bigl(108 + 12\sqrt{69}\bigr)^{2/3}(-1 - \sqrt{3}i) - 12(1 - \sqrt3 i)}{12 \cdot \bigl(108 + 12\sqrt{69}\bigr)^{1/3} }
\end{align*}

Comment: @Hagen I liked that crystal ball comment. This was helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The characteristic equation $z^3=z^2+1$ has a real root, let $t$, and a pair of complex conjugate roots $p\pm iq$, or $re^{\pm i\theta}$ in polar form.

The general solution is
$$T_n=At^n+B(re^{i\theta})^n+C(re^{-i\theta})^n.$$
Assuming that the initial values are real, so is the general solution, and by conjugation
$$At^n+B(re^{i\theta})^n+C(re^{-i\theta})^n=A^*t^n+B^*(re^{-i\theta})^n+C^*(re^{i\theta})^n.$$
This shows that $A$ is real, and $B, C$ are complex conjugates.
The general solution can be rewritten as
$$T_n=at^n+(b-ic)(re^{i\theta})^n+(b+ic)(re^{-i\theta})^n=at^n+2r^n(b\cos(n\theta)+c\sin(n\theta)).$$
It has a pure exponential term and an oscillating exponential term.